# Looping with an unsigned char

Tags: c, loops

What is an elegant way of executing something similar to this without entering an infinite loop, if `i` must be an `unsigned char`?

```
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", i); 
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
unsigned char i = 0;
do {
    printf("%u\n",i);
}while(++i != 0);
```

Do the increment in the loop test and test against the wrapped value.

Comment: Can the compiler unroll this?

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb: if your iterator variable needs to hold all values between 0 and "Uxxx_MAX", you picked a too narrow type for the algorithm.

You should have considered using `uint16_t` instead.

There are just so many cases where you *can't* use a large int type instead of your unsigned char. So let me ask you, is your application a real time embedded system, written for an 8-bit MCU, where you have found that this very loop is a performance bottleneck?

- If yes, then write an obscure loop with `uint8_t` as the type of the iterator, and comment why you did it.
- If no, then use `uint16_t` or a larger integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Put the check after the body and before the increment

```
for (unsigned char i = 0; ; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", i); 
    if(i==255)
        break;
}
```

But then you might as well do a while:

```
unsigned char i = 0;
while( ) {
    printf("%d\n", i); 
    if(i==255)
        break;
    ++i;
}
```

Or even push the check around:

```
for (unsigned char i = 0; i++ < 255; ) {
    printf("%d\n", i); 
}
```

All of these check for 255 before the increment, rather than checking for zero afterwards, so if the variable was a CHAR or some macro that was currently limited to 256 but could be changed, these would still work as they don't rely on overflow. Substitute `int` in there and it still works.

Comment: All of these examples are quite obscure, I wouldn't use nor recommend any of them.

Comment: @Lundin: Relying on overflow is also obscure, and does not explicitly show the number of iterations. I even wonder whether the compiler could unroll the loop, even though it is of static length?

Comment: Indeed, relying on overflow is obscure, even though it is well-defined. I suppose I'll write an answer on my own...  :)

Comment: @PhilH: Your first example works, but while( ) has a typo: I need a condition such as while(true).
Your third example is incorrect since it loops 255 times instead of the OP desire to loop 256 times.